How do you detect when Android's system language is changed in my React Native app?
How can I detect the change of Android's system language so that my app won't crash?
I have multiple components using i18next to translate. One such component is timeline.tsx as below
import '../locales/index';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const { t } = useTranslation();

./src/components/timeline.tsx
Index.js is defined as below.
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import en from './en.json';
import ja from './ja.json';

const resources = {
    en: {
        translation: en,
    },
    ja: {
        translation: ja,
    },
};

const languageDetector = {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    detect: (callback) => {
        const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
        const bestLanguage = locales[0]?.languageTag || 'en';
        callback(bestLanguage);
    },
    init: () => { },
    cacheUserLanguage: () => { },
};

i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    });

export default i18n;

./src/locales/index.js

Why is your app crashing? Did you try to see the logs?

VSCode immediately disconnects and shows no output. I'm new so if you can point me to learn how to get a crash log, I appreciate it.

I just learned abuot logcat (on android) and used it. Still learnning, but AI suggests the following.
E unknown:ReactNative: Tried to remove non-existent frame callback
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.memoma, PID: 32434
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.memoma/com.memoma.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception

I think a better approach will be using a lister and modify the methods in there, here is some approach you can follow up.

Modify index.js

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import en from './en.json';
import ja from './ja.json';

const resources = {
    en: {
        translation: en,
    },
    ja: {
        translation: ja,
    },
};

const languageDetector = {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    detect: (callback) => {
        const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
        const bestLanguage = locales[0]?.languageTag || 'en';
        callback(bestLanguage);
    },
    init: () => {},
    cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    });

export default i18n;


Function handle language changes

import i18n from './index';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';

const handleLocalizationChange = () => {
    const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
    const bestLanguage = locales[0]?.languageTag || 'en';
    i18n.changeLanguage(bestLanguage);
};

export default handleLocalizationChange;

you can call this in App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './locales';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import handleLocalizationChange from './locales/languageChangeHandler';

const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Set up the localization change listener
        RNLocalize.addEventListener('change', handleLocalizationChange);

        // Clean up the listener on unmount
        return () => {
            RNLocalize.removeEventListener('change', handleLocalizationChange);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            {/* Your app components */}
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
};

export default App;


Timeline.js

import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import '../locales/index';

const Timeline = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Your component JSX */}
            {t('your_translation_key')}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timeline;


This should make the transition smooth without any hiccups, This is somewhat similar to the approach I used. Feel free to make changes if necessary.


RNLocalize.addEventListener and RNLocalize.removeEventListener didn't work for me so I replaced them with AppState.addEventListener. Unfortunately, the app still crashes. I see no output on VSCode when it happens. I'm new and may not have configured logging properly.

RNLocalize.addEventListener should work for either case because they are native functions. Then better figure out why the app crashes. Have you tried getting analytics from a tool like Raygun?

I started a free trial of Raygun, followed the instruction to install it on my project, but the app now doesn't even launch with an error. So, I removed it. I tested my app without loading any element of i48next by commenting out relevant codes. I discovered the app still crashes on coming back from system setting right after I switch between Japanese and English. So, it appears the crash has nothing to do with the localization.

Seems like you have bigger issues to deal with. Raygun is a good tool, we are using it commercially for our analytics. But depending on the use cases the choice is yours.
Keep updating this thread, I would like to know how this will end
